# Is there a way to not open the splash screen/app when launching a shortcut action in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uiapplication, uiapplicationshortcutitem

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem,
                     completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if shortcutItem.type == "com.xyz.test.tests.firstAction" {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                }
                print("\(shortcutItem) was tapped")
            }
```

Here is the code i'm trying to execute. Is there a way to dismiss the application once the action is executed? If not i'm guessing it's required for context.

Answer (score 0):

try `exit(0)`, but you can't publish it

**Apple Review:**

> We found that your app includes a UI control for quitting the app.
>   This is not in compliance with the iOS Human Interface Guidelines, as
>   required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Please refer to the attached screenshot/s for reference.
>
> The iOS Human Interface Guidelines specify,
>
> "Always Be Prepared to Stop iOS applications stop when people press
>   the Home button to open a different application or use a device
>   feature, such as the phone. In particular, people don’t tap an
>   application close button or select Quit from a menu. To provide a good
>   stopping experience, an iOS application should:
>
> Save user data as soon as possible and as often as reasonable because
>   an exit or terminate notification can arrive at any time.
>
> Save the current state when stopping, at the finest level of detail
>   possible so that people don’t lose their context when they start the
>   application again. For example, if your app displays scrolling data,
>   save the current scroll position."
>
> > It would be appropriate to remove any mechanisms for quitting your app.

Comment: Thanks this worked for testing, need figure out an alternative to this.

Comment: @praza24 what do you mean on alternative?

Comment: I require this in production but as you mentioned earlier it won't get passed Apple. I guess UIApplication will always be required, upon clicking a shortcut and always launch the app even if it's not required.

Comment: @praza24 You can use fullscreen webView :) or SFSafariController

Comment: that's what i've done but the application still launches

Comment: @praza24if you are trying to create link app to some website, apple already has functionality to move some website to main screen.

Comment: I just need a browser to open in safari going to a website without the application launching

Comment: @praza24 so go to website then save it to home screen